# Why does text or graphics in premiere pro have two boxes?

Tags: premiere

First the red box is selected

[image]

now if you click outside and click near red box the main box is selected
[image]

moving this box also moves entire graphic

[image]

what is this box called, how do you center it etc.

GIF

[image]

UPDATE: it is NOT the black video...

[image]

Comment: Do you have anything else in your sequence? Can you add a screenshot of your whole premiere screen?

Comment: no there is nothing just create a new file and add text or a square you fill find it, let me make a gif

Comment: added a gif that shows the problems

Comment: How odd.. Deleted my answer because it's not correct.  I can't replicate what you're seeing.  Maybe it's a bug?  Update to latest version, reboot, etc?

Comment: I can't replicate it either.

Comment: ok ill update so it must be a bug, ill report if update fixes it